# Two Java Version(JDK 1.7 & JDK 1.8) on same machine

Tags: 14.04, java, jdk

My current Java version is

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

I want to install Java 8 too in same machine & use it as per my requirement.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS

Is that possible?
Please help!!

Comment: You want to use both? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I currently am running both Java 7 and Java 8 on my computer here is a link to the guide I used to install Java 8 http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/# This sets my default Java to 8, but if I want to run something under Java 7 I can right click as select run with openJDKJava7.

Hope this helps!